# Type traits in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
int main()
{
  struct C {
    C(const C&) = delete;
    C& operator= (const C&) = delete;

    C(C&&) {}
    C& operator=(C&&) { return *this; }
  };
  static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<C>::value &&
                    std::is_copy_constructible<C>::value,
                "");
}
```

Why above code can be successfully compiled in VS2013?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug.

Link1: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/800328/std-is-copy-constructible-is-broken

Link2: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/802032/std-is-copy-constructible-doesnt-work-correctly

Comment: Is there any implementation could work correctly? I have tried boost and the `is_constructible` part of libstdc++, but no one works correctly.